# Any other way to recover system?

Tags: internal-storage, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader

Past days my android phone got in bootloop. Since I didn't have access to PC, I tried some things from recovery. Tried to format dalvik-cache, but it failed because it was r/o. I tried installing SU, trying it again, remounting it as r/w but no success. Then I tried to backup and wipe data and system, then recover (stupid). I discovered that TWRP breaks everything when formatting. It broke data and system partitions and they were no longer mountable, I tried like 10 times reformatting them with no success. Then I decided to format Internal Storage (again stupid) and did it. Guess what? TWRP broke Internal Storage. Now I ended up in this: No recovery, no bootloader, no boot logo. Just black screen and vibrations indicating bootloop. Is there any way of recovering without service center?

Comment: What device, it could make a huge difference...

Comment: @acejavelin, Huawei G730-U10

Comment: If it shows up in Device Manager you *might* be able to use this method of hard brick recovery: http://howtounbrick.com/2016/06/10/how-to-unbrick-huawei-ascend-g730/

Comment: What do you mean by TWRP broke internal/data/system partition? Is TWRP faulty? On Huawei it was able to go to download mode by holding vol + & vol - & power at the same time, if you get some screen maybe it can help with recovering.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје, after TWRP formatted those partitions, they were unable to mount.

Comment: Windows see device as unrecognized device for some time until it reboots again (vibration)

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје when holding all those buttons together, it boots at black screen and just reboots again with vibration.

Comment: @acejavelin It won't enter download mode. It shows up in device manager as unrecognized only for a few seconds when trying to enter download mode.

Comment: No offense, but it sounds like it's bricked... It's 2.5 years old, might be time to let it go and get something different.

Comment: I still don't understand why TWRP screwed up partitions so they cannot be mounted. Well I must agree with acejavelin it sounds like hard brick. I suggest you to try to ask this on XDA developers, if this phone have separate forum there that's even better, if someone can help at this point it would be they

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје
Nobody helps me on XDA. Just no help at all. I already asked.

Comment: So you can't access the bootloader or recovery, and it doesn't show up in Device Manager ? Only other possibility is this: https://devs-lab.com/how-to-unbrick-mediatek-device.html Otherwise you might have to find some "financial possibilities" :/

Comment: @acejavelin
I tried that and found some new things. First is when I'm connecting phone to computer without battery in, led starts blinking red. Second, after installing drivers, windows recognized device and tried to install drivers for it, but failed. Still can't download anything in it. SP Flash Tool can't find device with battery in, nor with battery out. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Sorry... if you can't access the bootloader or SP Flash Tool doesn't see it, it's probably toast, that's all I got. :/

Comment: @acejavelin
Okay, at least you helped as you could.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can install TWRP again (if you dont have it) and try that:

goto: wipe>advanced wipe>select one of the broken file systems >press repair or change file system>repair file system

if that doesnt work:

goto: wipe>advanced wipe>select one of the broken file systems >press repair or change file system>change file system>ext4 or the file system that your rom initialy supports

then: reinstall your rom

Comment: How to install TWRP if no download mode or bootloader is working?

Comment: if the download mode is not working at all then you should use fastboot. If nothing is working your phone is bricked. If thats the case you should go to a customer service or try to find in the internet something like: unbrick Huawei G730-U10 there are flashtools for that.